# Calculating pdf between two probabilities in python

Tags: python, scipy

PDF of beta distribution looks like this:

[image: $ /alpha $]

I want to calculate probability that a 20%~30% products are defective where product defects can be represented with beta distribution where alpha =2, beta=5.

So using the formula it would be:

[image]

I want to calculate this using python.

following some stack overflow questions I've tried:

```
from scipy.stats import beta
beta_dist = beta(2,5)
beta_dist.pdf(0.3)
```

However cannot find pdf between 0.3~0.2

Comment: Do you want to the cdf maybe? Try `beta_dist.cdf(0.3) - beat_dist.cdf(0.2)` to get the increase in cumulative probability from 0.2 to 0.3.

Comment: ah yes cdf was what is needed, thanks!!